# Where are Azure SQL Database Backups Stored

Tags: backup, azure, storage, database, sql

I've got 5-6 Azure SQL Databases running. They run in the Basic and Standard pricing tiers. From what I've read backups run by default which allow for the Point in Time restore options to work.

These are my questions:

- **Where are these backups stored**?
- **Other than the default backups that run, is it possible to use the recovery services vault to back up Azure SQL Databases**? I've tried setting something up but I don't get an option for Azure SQL DB's, only Azure VM's and fileshares.

Answer (score 1):

1. The automated backups are stored automatically in Read-Access Geo-Redundant Storage (RA-GRS). Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups
2. You can't create manual backups in the traditional sense. You can set up the long term retention using the recovery services vault to retain what Azure does automatically. Reference: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5259/azure-sql-database-backup-and-restore-overview/

There are export and copy options, but not a traditional manual backup for Azure SQL Database.

Comment: I appreciate the link for the article. Is it possible to access these backups though? I'm not seeing anything in my existing storage accounts or any newly created storage accounts either.